# Dapper and list parameters return Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dapper

I have the following code that uses Dapper:

```
public async Task GetClientsInvoices(List<long> clients, List<int> invoices)
{
    var parameters = new
    {
        ClientIds = clients,
        InvoiceIds = invoices
    };

    string sqlQuery = "SELECT ClientId, InvoiceId, IsPaid" +
                       "FROM ClientInvoice " +
                       "WHERE ClientId IN ( @ClientIds ) " +
                       "AND InvoiceId IN ( @InvoiceIds )";

    var dbResult = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<ClientInvoicesResult>(sqlQuery, parameters);
}

public class ClientInvoicesResult
{
    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
}
```

which produces this based on sql server profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ClientId, InvoiceId, IsPaid FROM ClientInvoice WHERE ClientId IN ( (@ClientIds1) ) AND InvoiceId IN ( (@InvoiceIds1,@InvoiceIds2) )',N'@InvoiceIds1 int,@InvoiceIds2 int,@ClientIds1 bigint',InvoiceIds1=35,InvoiceIds2=34,ClientIds1=4
```

When it is executed I am getting the following error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong and I am getting this exception?
2. Why dapper translates this query and executes it using `sp_executesql` . How do I force it to use a normal select query like

   SELECT ClientId, InvoiceId, IsPaid
   FROM ClientInvoice
   WHERE ClientId IN (4)
   AND InvoiceId IN (34,35)

Comment: 1) Try removing the brackets after your `IN` statement (so `WHERE ClientId IN @ClientIds`). Looking at the profile, an extra set of brackets are being inserted already, and you don't need two sets. 2) It's a parameterised query: that's the point. If it simply substituted in raw values you'd be leaving yourself open to an SQL injection attack. Parameterised queries ensure this can't happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your profiled SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql
    N'SELECT ClientId, InvoiceId, IsPaid
        FROM ClientInvoice
        WHERE ClientId IN ( (@ClientIds1) )
        AND InvoiceId IN ( (@InvoiceIds1,@InvoiceIds2) )',
    N'@InvoiceIds1 int,@InvoiceIds2 int,@ClientIds1 bigint',InvoiceIds1=35,InvoiceIds2=34,ClientIds1=4
```

We can see that you've got two sets of brackets around `@ClientIds1` and `@InvoiceIds1,@InvoiceIds2`, the set which you wrote, and the set which Dapper (or a layer below it) is injecting.

Therefore, try removing the brackets which you added:

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT ClientId, InvoiceId, IsPaid " +
                   "FROM ClientInvoice " +
                   "WHERE ClientId IN @ClientIds " +
                   "AND InvoiceId IN @InvoiceIds";
```

This matches the code in the [Dapper README](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#list-support):

> Dapper allows you to pass in `IEnumerable<int>` and will automatically parameterize your query.
>
> For example:
>
> ```cs
> connection.Query<int>("select * from (select 1 as Id union all select 2 union all select 3) as X where Id in @Ids", new { Ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } });
> ```
>
> Will be translated to:
>
> ```cs
> select * from (select 1 as Id union all select 2 union all select 3) as X where Id in (@Ids1, @Ids2, @Ids3)" // @Ids1 = 1 , @Ids2 = 2 , @Ids2 = 3
> ```

Comment: thanks parentheses were a leftover from a copy/paste of sql's server query

Answer (score 4):

Remove the parentheses would fix the problem.

Wrong: "WHERE ClientId IN ( @ClientIds ) "

Correc: "WHERE ClientId IN @ClientIds "

Comment: Perfect. It's worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert the list into a string and pass as a comma-separated string:

```
var parameters = new
    {
        ClientIds = String.Join(",",clients),
        InvoiceIds = String.Join(",",invoices)
    };
```

Comment: This will try to cast nvarchar to int/bigint.